# Assigning a float value to a matrix of type Mat in Opencv

Tags: c++, mat, opencv3.0

Being new to Opencv is not easy. Here is the question.

I have a matrix of type CV_32FC that I want to fill it with a float value, acos(cos(delta[i])*cos(psi[j])), psi and delta are arrays.

so here is how I do it,

```
cv::Mat theta = cv::Mat::zeros(300,300,CV_32FC1);
for (int i = 0;i < 300;i++)
{
    for (int j = 0;j <300;j++)
    {
        theta.at<float>(i, j) = acos(cos(delta[i])*cos(psi[j]));
    }
 }

cout<<acos(cos(delta[10])*cos(psi[10]))<<endl;
cout<<theta.at<float>(10,10)<<endl;
```

but the two printed values are different!!!!!!!!!

What do you suggest guys?
M

Comment: perhaps cast the equation as a float, default is double

Comment: lets replace acos(cos(delta[i])*cos(psi[j])) with a float value, say 1.3456, still the printed values are different...:(

Comment: post both values to get an idea what you are looking at

Comment: In the for loop I use this instead :theta.at<float>(i, j) = 1.3688;

then 
cout<<theta.at<float>(10,10)<<endl; gives me the value 
-.0266557
wierd.....

Comment: first do something basic like float theta[10][10].
then do  theta[i][j] = {your eq}

Comment: can't reproduce your problem.